# Url link to feature image in the portfolio wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. i have issue with Feature image. just i need to add URL to feature image(when we click on that feature image , it should redirect to that particular URL).

also  is it possible to give URL to Title of the Portfolio categories page  which i used in normal page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code in your php file :

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail();
   echo '</a>';
 }?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, in which PHP File should add

Comment: If you working on inner page then you have to add in the page.php file.

Comment: problem is i could not find where is has_post_thumbnail() function i checked in page.php  its not avalable.

Comment: You need to customize your page.php file.
For this need to follow these steps :
1) Remove this code of line => "get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );"
2) Now add =>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail();
   echo '</a>';
the_title();
the_content();
 }?>

Comment: If you still didn't understand then i can do this.
You can send me your FTP details at amitnaraniwal7@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks . i will send mail.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?></a>
```

instead of this `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`  you can assign your own url

Comment: Thanks for your response, please could you tel me in which page the above changes has to be done. (using WordPress 4.1.5 version).

Comment: if you are using in post then it will be single.php file or else category.php

Comment: hi i have single.php in the mytheme folder . but  there is no <?php the_permalink(); ?>

Comment: if your using built in theme then you can find any plugin. i have posted that code for custom wordpress theme.

Comment: i am using xone wordpress theme

Answer (score 0):

use `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` for add Url link to feature image in portfolio in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,admin panel?

Comment: no,it's add on post.php file where your title display.add href link with this permalink .

Answer (score 0):

This worked finally.

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $sr_prefix.'_portfolio_externalurl', true); ?>"><?php } the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-crop-thumb');
```